# Python : my code is slow, using for loop with Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, execution-time, python-holidays

I got this code below which works fine but takes too much time to execute (**>30s**):

```
df['Date_engagement'] = np.nan
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
if not(pd.isna(df.loc[i,'Engagement'])):
    df.loc[i, 'Date_engagement'] = np.busday_offset(
        df.loc[i, 'Date_réception'].date(),
        df.loc[i,'Engagement'], roll='backward', busdaycal=france_bdc
    )
```

I guess this is because I loop through the Pandas dataframe, and I wonder if there is a way to achieve the same result, not using any loop.

Basically what this code does is creating the ***'Date_engagement'*** column which will be the result of adding ***'Engagement'*** days to ***'Date_réception'*** if ***'Engagement'** *is not empty. I use ***'np.busday_offset()'** *to avoid holidays.

Thanks in advance for your help...

I tried to use Pandas features for dataframes (like ***DataFrame.apply()***), but can't find how to do it correctly to get the same result as explained.

Comment: _"using for loop with Pandas dataframe"_ is an immediate red flag.  A major advantage of the dataframe is to vectorise

Comment: if you post what you are trying to achieve, than it will be more than likely that we (SO contributors) can help you increase speed > 10x...  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the input dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date_réception': ['2023-05-12', '2023-05-13'],
                   'Engagement': [10, np.nan]})
print(df)

# Output
  Date_réception  Engagement
0     2023-05-12        10.0
1     2023-05-13         NaN
```

You can vectorize your code:

```
france_bdc = np.busdaycalendar(weekmask='1111100', holidays=['2023-05-18'])
m = df['Engagement'].notna()

df.loc[m, 'Date_engagement'] = (
    np.busday_offset(df.loc[m, 'Date_réception'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'),
                     df.loc[m, 'Engagement'], roll='backward', busdaycal=france_bdc)
)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Date_réception  Engagement Date_engagement
0     2023-05-12        10.0      2023-05-29
1     2023-05-13         NaN             NaT
```

Comment: This works just great, in much much less time! (<0.2s)
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work:

```
mask = df['Engagement'].notnull()

df.loc[mask, 'Date_engagement'] = np.busday_offset(
    df.loc[mask, 'Date_réception'].dt.date,
    df.loc[mask, 'Engagement'],
    roll='backward',
    busdaycal=france_bdc
)
```

Comment: Here 'dt.date' issues a TypeError:
 TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('<M8[D]') according to the rule 'safe'.
Using values.astype('datetime64[D]') instead works fine. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient one but you can still try it :

```
dt_arr = np.busday_offset(
            df["Date_réception"].to_numpy().astype("datetime64[D]"),
            df["Engagement"].fillna(0), roll="backward", busdaycal=france_bdc)

df["Date_engagement"] = pd.Series(dt_arr).where(df["Engagement"].notna())

#620 µs ± 15.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

---

Example :

```
np.random.seed(1)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Date_réception": pd.date_range("20230401", periods=30, freq="W"),
    "Engagement": np.random.choice(np.append(np.random.randint(5, 26, 25), [np.nan]),
                                   size=30, replace=True)}
)

france_bdc = np.busdaycalendar(
                holidays=["2023-01-01", "2023-04-17", "2023-05-01",
                          "2023-05-08", "2023-07-14", "2023-08-15",
                          "2023-11-01", "2023-11-11", "2023-12-25"]
)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

   Date_réception  Engagement Date_engagement
0      2023-04-02        23.0      2023-05-05
1      2023-04-09        23.0      2023-05-15
2      2023-04-16        21.0      2023-05-18
3      2023-04-23        10.0      2023-05-09
4      2023-04-30        23.0      2023-06-02
5      2023-05-07        10.0      2023-05-22
6      2023-05-14        19.0      2023-06-08
7      2023-05-21        18.0      2023-06-14
8      2023-05-28        21.0      2023-06-26
9      2023-06-04        21.0      2023-07-03
10     2023-06-11        20.0      2023-07-07
11     2023-06-18        19.0      2023-07-13
12     2023-06-25         NaN             NaT
13     2023-07-02        16.0      2023-07-25
14     2023-07-09        10.0      2023-07-24
15     2023-07-16        10.0      2023-07-28
16     2023-07-23         5.0      2023-07-28
17     2023-07-30         9.0      2023-08-10
18     2023-08-06        18.0      2023-08-31
19     2023-08-13        25.0      2023-09-18
20     2023-08-20        23.0      2023-09-20
21     2023-08-27         6.0      2023-09-04
22     2023-09-03         NaN             NaT
23     2023-09-10         5.0      2023-09-15
24     2023-09-17        20.0      2023-10-13
25     2023-09-24        13.0      2023-10-11
26     2023-10-01        10.0      2023-10-13
27     2023-10-08        15.0      2023-10-27
28     2023-10-15        10.0      2023-10-27
29     2023-10-22         NaN             NaT
```